# Vuejs - Child component reset when re-indexing array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have an array of objects

```
const array = [
  {
    id: uniqueId,
    childs: [
      {
        id: uniqueId
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: uniqueId,
    childs: [
      {
        id: uniqueId
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

and a loop

```
<template v-for="(item, index_item) in array" :key="item.id">
  <div>
    <template v-for="(child, index_child) in item.childs" :key="child.id">
      <button type="button" @click.prevent="addChild(index_item, index_child)"></button>

      <FileUploader></FileUploader>

      <button type="button" @click.prevent="addChild(index_item, index_child + 1)"></button>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

and the addChild method

```
const addChild = (index_item, index_child) => {
  array[index_item].childs.splice(index_child, 0, {id : uniqueId}
}
```

If i add a child as the last of childs array, there are no side effects, but if indexes of the childs array change, the file inputs inside FileUploader components are reset
I've tried to give the FileUploader a unique key like :key="child.id + index_child", or the key of the child, with no result.

I can't figure how not to reset my components while re-indexing the array.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Don't use the index in your key, only use something unique like an id

Comment: `:key="item.id"` and `:key="child.id"` @Lk77 - aren't they already doing that?

Comment: @JaromandaX my comment is about the `:key="child.id + index_child"` part

Comment: Oh, I only read the code @Lk77:p

Comment: Thank you guys. @Lk77 i tried with the child key, and also i just tried with a unique id generated only for the FileUploader, and no better result, reindexing still reset the input

Comment: Then it's in the FileUploader, try puting keys on the input fields, i have the same setup as you with a v-for and add/remove functions that splice the array, and it works fine, but every input as a `:key="uniqueId"` and vue correctly reuse/move that input at the correct index

Comment: @Lk77 I tried to add a uniqueId on the input. When i reindex the childs, the FileUploader is like a new component, with another uniqueId. It seems the component is re-rendered when reindexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

You code could use the same `uniqueId` for array items. If so fix that with provided real unique IDs for each array item.

Comment: Thank you. I use a uuid generator and i have checked in Vue Dev Tools and in the code on the input, ids are unique. But while reindexing the component is re-rendered, so the id changes..

Comment: @jurandou how you change indexes? sort the array?

Comment: While trying to add more of my code on your SFC playground it works... I'm about to start it again from scratch, i dont know what's going wrong...

Comment: Yes you helped me a lot, thank you so much for your time